# I think that the default user's description is wrong

Tags: discussion

When I view the profile of anybody that hasn't filled it's bio it says this:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about **them**.

I think that it should say this instead:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about **it**.

I've highlighted what I think that is a fail. However English is not my mother tongue.

I think that this may refer to the user and not to a bunch of users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*They*/*them*/*their* is common when referring to the third-person singular for a person of unknown gender. *It*, on the other hand, doesn't enjoy similar popularity. *It*, to me, is for inanimate, inhuman or subhuman entities.

Related:

- [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48/93130)

Comment: Ok, sorry, as I said, English is not my mother tongue. I didn't know this.

Comment: Just to be pedantic about it the correct English for this would be `Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about there self`

Comment: @markkirby assuming you meant "their self", I have never seen anybody say "an air of mystery about X's self" - it's always "an air of mystery about X", or "... around X".

Comment: "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about their self" would be correct as a general statement but if you know the name it would be "Apparently, X prefers to keep an air of mystery about their self"

Comment: replacing their with him/her if you know the gender ie him self or her self.

Comment: @markkirby you're missing the point. "self" just doesn't belong in that phrase.

Comment: "them" implies a multiple ie "did you see all of them today" "how many of them do you have", while "self" implies that a single person is doing this ie "this guy hurt him self" or "she did not want to talk about her self"